# Core Bluetooth: CBPeripheral disconnects every ~10 seconds

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am seeing a weird bug in iOS 8.3 and am wondering if anyone else is seeing the same thing.

I have an iPad Air (in Central mode) and an iPhone 6 (in Peripheral mode) in very close proximity.

- My `CBCentralManager` is initialized with a serial background queue and the `CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey` option
- The manager starts scanning for peripherals using the `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true` option
- Within `centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:` I check against a list of peripherals that are already discovered:

> ```
> let connect: () -> () = {
>   peripheral.delegate = self
>   self.devices[peripheral.identifier.UUIDString] = peripheral
>   self.manager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
> }
>
> if let device = devices[peripheral.identifier.UUIDString] {
>   if device.peripheral.state == .Disconnected {
>     connect()
>   }
> } else if peripheral.state == .Disconnected {
>   connect()
> }
> ```

- Once connected, I discover services and characteristics.

**The peripheral now disconnects after about 10 seconds, is immediately discovered again and connects again. 10 seconds later this procedure repeats itself.**

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

I have also tried to directly subscribe to a characteristic on the peripheral, but this did not seem to change anything.

Comment: I used my test app on an iOS8.3 device and I don't see this - both with a Fitbit Flex peripheral and another iOS device as a peripheral.  Is there a particular reason you are setting the allow duplicates key?  It isn't normally necessary and drains battery.  I have no problem maintaining connection to a BLE peripheral for hours.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I am using the duplicates key to perform actions based on the RSSI. Do you connect to the peripheral once? What characteristics do you read/write/subscribe to? Does the peripheral update values continously? I think it might have something to do with that?

Comment: I connect to the peripheral once.  If you want to get the RSSI value of the connected peripheral, you can use the `readRSSI` CBPeripheral method.  My sample code doesn't continually read/write or notify on any characteristic

Comment: Would love to take a look at your sample? Is it on github maybe?

Comment: Yes https://github.com/paulw11/BTBackground

Comment: How did you fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is an expected behaviour. Bluetooth was designed to consume very little amount of energy so it drops the connection as soon as possible. Also at least in iOS 7 it was not necessary to rediscover peripheral device - you was able to reconnect to already discovered device after disconnection. I am pretty sure it is also true for iOS 8. The recommended way to work with BLE if you do not need a permanent connection is:

1. Discover
2. Connect
3. Read/write all you need as soon as possible
4. Setup timer
5. When timer fires go to point 2

If you need a permanent connection (for example you need to take data about heart rate in real time) you should subscribe for characteristic with [- setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheral/setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic:)

> When you enable notifications for characteristic’s value, the
>   peripheral calls the
>   peripheral:didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:error: method
>   of its delegate object to notify your app when the characteristic’s
>   value changes. Because it is the peripheral that chooses when to send
>   an update, your app should be prepared to handle them as long as
>   notifications or indications remain enabled.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to subscribe to a peripheral's notify characteristic after connection, but the connection is dropped nevertheless. Do you know if the notify characteristic actually needs to emit any data in order for the two devices to stay connected?

Comment: @desktop Yes, it should emit some data but I do not know how often. Probably it is described somewhere inside BLE specification https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/adopted-specifications

Answer (score 1):

It helped me to send messages (not commands - anything) back to peripheral from time to time.

Comment: how is this answering the question?

Comment: When I started sending messages to my peripheral (like "pong"  answering "ping") it stopped disconnecting every n seconds. I thought that it was the main question  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯